# Trying to change the value of Database.Connection.ConnectionString in c# fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have a piece of unit test code written in c# that connects to a database through Entity Framework 6.1.3.

But when I try to assign the value of a correct connection string to Database.Connection.ConnectionString, the ConnectionString keeps its previous value and does not change.

It's like Database.Connection.ConnectionString was readonly, though it has a get and a set in its definition.

My code  simply looks like this:

```
Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
```

And the ConnectionString property is like this:

```
  public abstract class DbConnection : Component, IDbConnection, IDisposable
  {
    private StateChangeEventHandler _stateChangeEventHandler;
    internal bool _supressStateChangeForReconnection;

    [DefaultValue("")]
    [ResCategory("DataCategory_Data")]
    [RecommendedAsConfigurable(true)]
    [SettingsBindable(true)]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    public abstract string ConnectionString { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, and it has nothing to do with the subject of my question.
The password was not showing when I was assigning a connection string to the ConnectionString property but it's obviously for security reasons that Entity Framework hides the password.
My connection problem to the database was due for another reason.